# Find the matrix associated to cyclic rotation of a matrix

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $A\in \mathbb{GF(2)}$ a matrix with dimensions $N,M$. Let $f_{x,y}$ a function that do cyclic shift to the rights by $x$ and to up by $y$.

Example
Let $A$ be
\begin{matrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i\\
\end{matrix}
the $f_{4,1}(A)$ is

\begin{matrix}
f &d & e\\
i&g & h\\
c & a & b\\
\end{matrix}

Could you help to find the matrix associated with this linear transformation $f_{x,y}$.

Comment: is a cyclic shift

Comment: Yes, so $f_{4,1}=f_{1,1}$ here, right?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly